# Checking and changing a value in an array

Tags: php

I have a multi-array stored in a SESSION

I loop through the data in order to change a value which is set to "1" and set it to "0"

But for some reason its not changing it even though it does find the value.

This is what i have:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 0 
    [2] => admin_user
    [8] => 1 
    [3] => 2
    [4] => Array (
        [7] => Array ( 
            [0] => User1
            [1] => 1 
            [2] => 1 
            [3] => w.jpg 
            [4] => 1 
            [5] => 1 
            [6] => 500 
            [7] => 50
            [8] => 3000 
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => User2 
            [1] => 1 
            [2] => 3 
            [3] => d.jpg 
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 0 
            [6] => 200 
            [7] => 85 
            [8] => 5000
        ) 
    )
)
```

So in PHP I'm trying to change the value of position 5 in the arrays at position 4.

This is how i did it:

```
foreach($_SESSION['player_data'][4] as $key){
    if($key[5] == 1){
       $_SESSION['player_data'][4][$key][5] = 0;
       break;
    }
}
```

But it will not set it to 0 it stays as 1 its annoying :( where am i going wrong?

Comment: `$key` is not your key, it's a value. Do `foreach($_SESSION['player_data'][4] as $key => $value)` instead

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first - do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log

Comment: The foreach and if check `$_SESSION['player_data'][4][5]`.  You set `$_SESSION['player_data'][4][$key][5]`.

Comment: @stevether: I didn't see your comment when I posted. Then I went to up vote your answer and it was gone. So: Good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
foreach($_SESSION['player_data'][4] as $key => $value){    
   if($value[5] == 1){
       $_SESSION['player_data'][4][$key][5] = 0;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent this has fixed the problem, i was getting confused with all these keys and values! Thanks for clearing it up!